# In Rust, is there any way to change a struct/type to be "Send"?

Tags: rust

I've hit the issue a couple of times of trying to pass things into the `spawn` function (to create a new thread/task) and have the compiler tell me `error: cannot capture variable of type "blah blah", which does not fulfill "Send", in a bounded closure`.

**Is there a way to transform a type be able to fulfill "Send" or is that fixed based on some set of rules?**

For example, I can easily implement the `ToStr` trait by using a directive like this:

```rust
#[deriving(ToStr, Rand)]
struct Point {
    x: int,
    y: int,
}
```

Can I do something similar for the `Send` trait?  Or are "kind" Traits treated differently?

Here's a concrete example of this issue - **is there some way to overcome it?**

```rust
fn create_process_options(cmdinfo: &CmdInfo) -> (ProcessOptions, Option<FileDesc>) {
// ... omitted
}

// "po" is of type std::run::ProcessOptions
let (po, filedesc_opt) = create_process_options(&cmdinfo);
spawn(proc() {
    let mut ps = Process::new(cmdinfo.program, cmdinfo.args, po).expect("darn");
    ps.finish();
});
```

Compiler error:

```
error: cannot capture variable of type `std::run::ProcessOptions<>`, which does not fulfill `Send`, in a bounded closure
let mut process = Process::new(cmdinfo.program, cmdinfo.args, po).expect("darn");
                                                              ^~
note: this closure's environment must satisfy `Send`
let mut process = Process::new(cmdinfo.program, cmdinfo.args, po).expect("darn");
```

Comment: This is because of the `dir: Option<&'a Path>` field of `ProcessOptions<'a>`. Structures containing references cannot be `Send`. The remaining question is why it is `&Path` and not `Path`. The answer for that appears to be that `std::io::process::ProcessConfig` uses mostly references, including `cwd: Option<&str>` which may come from `ProcessOptions.dir`.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the explanation. I can see why those limits are placed, but it does make it a landmine when trying to do multi-threaded/tasked programming.

Comment: @quux00: Actually, I would argue that it would be a landmine in C++ (as it would sometimes explodes in your face), while in Rust all you get is a stern refusal to proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send is a rust *Kind*, the other things you mentioned are *Traits*. While both can be used to bound generics, they are in fact quite different. You have to opt-in to a Trait, but what Kinds a type has are inferred based on their contents - besides changing the contents you can't change the Kind of a type.

For most Kinds, the rule is "a type X is of Kind Y if all the members of X are of Kind Y."

In this case, since being Send requires that you fulfill `'static`, which means that they don't contain any non-`'static` references. Since `ProcessOptions` contains a non-static lifetime `Option<&'a Path>`, like Chris Morgan detailed in his comment, `ProcessOptions` does not fulfill Send.